# Buttons shapes possible with php/css/html?

Tags: php, html, css, forms, button

I am creating a login form and would like to have nice buttons. I saw an example of these buttons online. Is this possible with html/css/php?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Comment: Yes. Two buttons + CSS.

Comment: Please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: HTML + CSS, *not* PHP. Did you try using your browser's dev tools to inspect the code for those buttons on the page where you saw them? (In most modern browsers, simply right-click on the element you're interested in and press "Inspect" or "Inspect Element", and the dev tools will show you the element's HTML and associated CSS.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible using html/php with css,
simply add these lines to your css code (assuming button not in a division and all button will have same look)

```
button{ //your code here }
```

or if it's in a division you can do it just like this

```
.divclass button{ //your code here}
```

you can add any styling there like background-color, color, font-style, etc.
and you can do something like

```css
.button button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.hover button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black; 
    border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}

.button1:hover {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

.button2 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black; 
    border: 2px solid #008CBA;
}

.button2:hover {
    background-color: #008CBA;
    color: white;
}

.button3 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black; 
    border: 2px solid #f44336;
}

.button3:hover {
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
}

.button4 {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.button4:hover {background-color: #e7e7e7;}

.button5 {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #555555;
}

.button5:hover {
    background-color: #555555;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="button"><button>Click Me</button></div><br>Hoverable <br>
<div class="hover">

<button class="button button2">Blue</button>
<button class="button button3">Red</button>
<button class="button button4">Gray</button>
<button class="button button5">Black</button>
</div>
```

for hoverable button you can do

button:hover{ //your code here }

that can make your button have different view when it hovered
and you can find another example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_buttons.asp)

For rounded button you can add `border-radius` in your style, the value can be in px or %

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {border-radius: 2px;}
.button2 {border-radius: 4px;}
.button3 {border-radius: 8px;}
.button4 {border-radius: 12px;}
.button5 {border-radius: 50%;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Rounded Buttons</h2>
<p>Add rounded corners to a button with the border-radius property:</p>

<button class="button button1">2px</button>
<button class="button button2">4px</button>
<button class="button button3">8px</button>
<button class="button button4">12px</button>
<button class="button button5">50%</button>

</body>
</html>
```

ps: sorry for bad english and I a little forgot about css, so just try to look at the link I given above

Comment: Isn't the OP asking how to style buttons with curved edges as shown in the screenshot in the question?

Comment: Sorry the image failed to load in my browser, to style rounded button the example is available in the link i've given [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_buttons.asp), but thanks i will edit my post

Answer (score 1):

after i've seen your image, I was interested to make that button, I've done it but maybe this is not what you're looking for but i think you can play with them..

------ css ----------

```
body{
height:1000px;
background-color: gray;
}
.buttonContainer{
padding:8px;
max-width: 350px;
background-color:#333333;
color : white;
margin-left : 200px;
}

.button{
background-color:#0066ff;
padding : 8px;
border:none;
color:#fff;
width : 150px;
height : 40px;
margin 8px;
}
.button1{
background-color:#333333;
width:50px;
border-radius:40px;
margin-left:-20px;
margin-right:-10px; 
weight:3;
position:absolute;
z-index:4; 
}
```

-----------html----------------

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="buttonContainer"><center>
    <button class='button'><b>LOGIN</b></button>
    <button class='button button1' disabled>OR</button>
    <button class='button'><b>SIGNUP</b></button></center>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

```css
body{
height:1000px;
background-color: gray;
}
.buttonContainer{
padding:8px;
max-width: 350px;
background-color:#333333;
color : white;
}

.button{
background-color:#0066ff;
padding : 8px;
border:none;
color:#fff;
width : 150px;
height : 40px;
margin 8px;
}
.button1{
background-color:#333333;
width:50px;
border-radius:40px;
margin-left:-20px;
margin-right:-10px;
weight:3;
position:absolute;
z-index:4;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="buttonContainer"><center>
  <button class='button'><b>LOGIN</b></button>
  <button class='button button1' disabled>OR</button>
  <button class='button'><b>SIGNUP</b></button></center>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```